# Email configuration troubleshooting in localhost website

Tags: orchardcms

I simply added the following SMTP details:

[image: Orchard STMP settings]

What's wrong with my configuration then?

Why is that I can't receive any new emails on my gmail account.

Please help me with these. Thank you.

Comment: Any errors in AppData/Logs?

Comment: Using Fiddler while a mail should be sent may help too. Many things can go wrong, most of which will be in logs. It could be bad password, firewall configuration...

Comment: No, there isn't any error related with this issue in the logs. And someone let me try the port 25 but always failure :(

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue.  Specifically for Gmail I had go to my Google Account Settings and first enable 2-Step Verification.  Once that was enabled I could create 'App Passwords'.

This creates a custom password for login and bypasses the 2-step verification. Copy and paste that in your password for login.

The reason this did not work for me even without 2-Step verification enabled is because it was presenting the application originally with a Captcha to solve.