# could not send email when submitting a form in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, sendmail

I Use `Orchard 1.10.1`. I get this error in `AppData/Logs` after submitting a form that has a send email activity.

```
2016-12-01 10:39:07,242 [11] Orchard.Email.Services.SmtpMessageChannel - 
Default - Could not send email [http://yxyxyx.com/Orchard.DynamicForms/Form/Submit]
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network [2a00:1450:400c:c04::6d]:587
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Orchard.Email.Services.SmtpMessageChannel.Process(IDictionary`2 parameters)
```

How should I solve this issue?

---------Update---------

Test send email in configuration fails. It is my configuration:
[image]

Comment: Check if your mail server SSL port is 587!

Comment: Try the default port number 25. If this is not working then please explain where you got the configuration data. The docs say QMail listens to port 25 by default.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a faulty SMTP configuration because the log states:

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
```

Fix your [configuration](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Configuring-email/) and the error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

As @ViRuSTriNiTy has already said - it is almost certainly a configuration issue form that error message.

Go to the Settings page in the Admin panel and click on the Email option. This page also allows you to send a test email based on your current settings.

First of all make sure you can send a test email on that page. If you can't, then it's your email configuration. If you can, then it's something on the page your form is on.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I updated the question. I don't know whats wrong with this configuration.

Comment: We use Gmail in Orchard for pretty much everything and that configuration looks correct. You're not stuck behind a firewall or anything are you?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try at port 465? This is the default SSL port for gmail. 587 requires TLS. I don't think gmail servers will ever relay smtp at port 25, unless you are targeting other gmail users.

host name: smtp.gmail.com
Port 465 (SSL required)
Port 587 (TLS required)

In any case, it is definitely a network related issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52539408/2324708

To summarize, In my case Orchard was getting presented with Captcha / 2 Step Verification from Gmail which it is unable to solve itself.

In Google account settings I added '2 Step Verification' and then create an 'App Password'.  Replacing the google account password with this 'App Password' did the trick for me.